# Example of using a TraceSource with Common.Logging

Tags: common.logging, tracesource

I've read this question and I know its possible:
[Common.Logging for TraceSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847401/common-logging-for-tracesource)

Can someone please post an example.
Also it could be helpfull if it can be configured to use the TraceSource in code instead of using the .config file.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to have Common.Logging forward messages to a TraceSource, then your logger name and tracesource name have to match.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="common">
      <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <common>
    <logging>
      <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Simple.TraceLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging">
        <arg key="level" value="ALL" />
        <arg key="showLogName" value="true" />
        <arg key="showDataTime" value="true" />
        <arg key="dateTimeFormat" value="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:fff" />
        <arg key="useTraceSource" value="true" />
      </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
  </common>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="SomeSourceName" switchName="YourSwitch">
        <listeners>
          <add name="EventLog" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" initializeData="Application"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="YourSwitch" value="Information"/>
    </switches>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

And from code you write:

```
var logger = Common.Logging.LogManager.GetLogger("SomeSourceName");
```

Hope this helps even though the post is 2 months old and the tracesouce is setup via .config.

Comment: Don't forget about useTraceSource flag. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847401/common-logging-for-tracesource